# Numpy sum over repeated entries in index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, sum

Given numpy ndarray `A` and an integer array `I`, of the same shape, with highest value `imax` and an array `B = np.zeros(imax)` we can do `B[I] = A`. However if `I` has repeated entries the last assignment holds. I need to do this while summing over repeated entries instead, like

```
For i in range(A.size):
    B[I.ravel()[i]] += A.ravel()[i]
```

Is there a good way to do this in `numpy`?

For example, I want this behavior (but neither `=` nor `+=` works like this)

```
A = np.array((1,2,5,9))
I = np.array((0,1,2,0),dtype=int)
B = np.zeros(3)
B[I] += A
print(B)
>>> array([10,2,5])
```

Here we see `1+9=10` in the first entry.

Comment: Your question would become clearer (and easier to answer correctly), if you provided an example of data that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `add.at` provides an un-buffered addition for use when you have index duplicates

Comment: @Grismar I added an example!

Comment: @hpaulj That is the answer, thanks a lot! If you want to make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [1]: A = np.array((1,2,5,9)) 
   ...: I = np.array((0,1,2,0),dtype=int) 
   ...: B = np.zeros(3) 
   ...: B[I] += A                                                                                                          
In [2]: B                                                                                                                  
Out[2]: array([9., 2., 5.])
```

This a buffered solution, different from an iterative one:

```
In [3]: B = np.zeros(3)                                                                                                    
In [4]: for i,a in zip(I,A): 
   ...:     B[i] += a 
   ...:                                                                                                                    
In [5]: B                                                                                                                  
Out[5]: array([10.,  2.,  5.])
```

The unbuffered solution using the `ufunc.at`:

```
In [6]: B = np.zeros(3)                                                                                                    
In [7]: np.add.at(B, I, A)                                                                                                 
In [8]: B                                                                                                                  
Out[8]: array([10.,  2.,  5.])
```